# Magento2 deploy static files overwrite instead of manually delete

Tags: magento2, static-content, static-content-deploy

When I run `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` 
it does not overwrite existing files but leaves them intact.

This leads to the unpleasant situation that I have to clear **static** file before I regenerate them. In the meantime my store is unaccessible. 
It would be so much easier if the files would remain in place and then just overwritten when the new file comes in.

Does anyone have a working solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

**Delete from you root directory :**

```
var/cache
var/generation
```

**Please run below commands:**

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento c:c
bin/magento c:f
```

Comment: How does this relate to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Alas, there *always* is way around... Here it is to use more than one locale. Magento indeed does not overwrite files if they exist, so you have to delete files before re-generating them. BUT if you generate files for more than one locale magento copies the files afterwards and overwrites exisiting files.

I use en_US and de_DE locales so I can do:

rm -rf pub/static/adminhtm/Magento/backend/es_ES;
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy es_US de_DE --area=adminhtml

to first clear all (unused) files in es_ES directory, generate them again and then have them copied very fast to the directories I need them in.